# How can I avoid circular logic when synchronizing Java Threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Jersey REST service method that accesses a cache.  This method keeps track of the `requestsBeingProcessed` because a `MessageService` periodically updates the cache, but can only do so when there are no requests being processed.  The calls to increment and decrement the number of requests being processed are synchronized to ensure thread-safe access.

```
class TeamInfoService {
    @GET
    @Path("/{teamId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getTeamInfo(@PathParam("teamId") final int teamId) {
        MessageService.incrementRequestsBeingProcessed;
        String team = teamCache.getTeams().get(teamId);
        MessageService.decrementRequestsBeingProcessed;
        return team;
    }
}

class MessageService {
    private static int requestsBeingProcessed = 0;

    public synchronized static void incrementRequestsBeingProcessed() {
        requestsBeingProcessed++;
    }

    public synchronized static void decrementRequestsBeingProcessed() {
        requestsBeingProcessed--;
    }

    public synchronized static void getRequestsBeingProcessed() {
        return requestsBeingProcessed;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `MessageService` has to acquire a lock to update the cache, but can only update it by checking `requestsBeingProcessed`, which can only be accessed by one thread at a time.

```
public synchronized static void updateCache(String message) {
    while(getRequestsBeingProcessed() != 0) {
        //wait until there are no requests being processed
    }        
    processMessage(message);
}
```

I have a chicken/egg situation here:  I can't get the lock to update `requestsBeingProcessed` because a lock is required to check `requestsBeingProcessed`.  Is there a different way I should be approaching this problem?

Comment: If you want to use the basic concurrency primitives directly, then you should looke at `Object.wait` and `Object.notify`/`Object.notifyAll`. In the `decrementRequestsBeingProcessed` method, when you detect that requestsBeingProcessed reaches zero, you can call `notify`. This unlocks the synchronized monitor while `notify` is executing - check the Javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to notify updating thread whenever there's no items in queue:

```
public synchronized static void decrementRequestsBeingProcessed() {
        if (requestsBeingProcessed > 0) requestsBeingProcessed--;        
        if (requestsBeingProcessed == 0) MessageService.class.notifyAll();
}

public synchronized static void updateCache(String message) {
    try {
       while(getRequestsBeingProcessed() != 0) {
        MessageService.class.wait();
       }
       processMessage(message);
    } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      // devise cancellation strategy here...
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against this approach.  As you're discovering, writing multi-threaded code is hard even for smart people.

Another approach you could try would be a [producer/consumer](http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem) arrangement with a blocking deque.  The required threading is built in; you don't have to deal with it.

I would also consider a caching solution like [JCS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/) rather than writing your own.  Your service should work even if caching is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

If your service can only be called by one thread at a time, then you just LOCK THE SERVICE! Why do you use a integer variable and lock the integer variable?

However, in your case, maybe a message queue or something like that is a graceful solution.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to implement it - your tactic is the description of a semaphore. You can see how semaphores work in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29) and the class in Java in [the oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: I tried using a semaphore first and ran into the same problem.  I need to acquire the lock and wait until `requestsBeingProcessed` reaches 0, but the other thread needs to acquire the lock in order to update `requestsBeingProcessed`.